# Access caller's domain name in RESTful WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

I have developed a simple RESTFul WCF service, the service has public IP an d no API key.

However I would like to limit the access to the service from certein domains. (e.g. only from xyz.com and not  from abc.com)

How can we know from which domain the call to the service is originated and is there any efficient way to filter unwanted calls in configuration level only.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a firewall problem, I would use that instead of any application level filtering. It's more secure and arguably much faster.